# OTRS v4 Soap/Rest response limit to 500 results

Tags: rest, soap, otrs, ticket-system

I am pulling tickets from OTRS server (I set up GenericTicketConnector and I use both Soap and Rest protocols).

For example when I try to extract all tickets from specific queue, my response is always limited to 500 results (8000+ tickets in the queue currently). 
Example:

```
curl "https://localhost/otrs/nph-genericinterface.pl/Webservice/GenericTicketConnectorREST/Ticket?UserLogin=user&Password=pass&Queue=ExampleQueue"
```

How can I get all tickets from a queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually simple, but it is not documented in their API docs. requests pagination didn't work too. The way to do it is to pass Limit=(any integer) in the url